# Javascript regex : remove text between HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to remove text that is between any HTML tags :

example :

```
<div>
   <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

my var result should be :

```
<div>
    <h1></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Use the DOM, seriously.

Comment: If you want to modify live tags on a page, just set their textContent empty.

Comment: loop through all the childern of body tag and $(this).empty() its cotent

Comment: blanking the textContent or using empty() on everything could destroy sub-nodes...

Answer (score 6):

If, as your question suggests, you want to remove *all* text from between *any* HTML tags… only the real DOM is going to cut it.

```
function removeAllTextNodes(node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    } else if (node.childNodes) {
        for (var i = node.childNodes.length; i--;) {
            removeAllTextNodes(node.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This, unlike `textContent` and `innerHTML`, will keep all existing element structure in place and remove only text.

If you really have a string and are using client-side JavaScript in a browser, and the string represents part of a document’s content (and not an entire document – i.e. you won’t find any DTD, `<html>`, `<head>`, or `<body>` elements within), then you can parse it just by putting it into an element:

```
var container = document.createElement("div");
container.innerHTML = htmlString;
removeAllTextNodes(container);
return container.innerHTML;
```

Otherwise, you’ll probably want an HTML parser for JavaScript. Regular expressions, as it’s been noted, aren’t great at parsing HTML.

Answer (score 4):

VANILLA JS TO THE RESCUE

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML = "";
}
```

Just insert any tag you'd like and wallah, no need for regex, or a 90kb library.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript is already able to accomplish this with built in functions in a way that in conceptually superior to regex

```
<div>
   <h1 id="foo">Title</h1>
</div>
<script>
   document.getElementById("foo").textContent = ""
</script>
```

Comment: `innerText` is non-standard and will not work in browsers like Firefox. It's an IE extension that chrome supports to work better on IE sites. Maybe you meant `.innerHTML` or `.textContent` ?

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to do something like this;

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    if(element.children.length === 0) {
        elements[i].textContent = '';
    }
}
```

This

- Finds all elements
- Loops through them
- Removes any text content

Docs:

- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)
- [Element.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName)
- [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

You can also make this re-usable like so

```
var removeAllText = function() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        if(element.children.length === 0) {
            elements[i].textContent = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Then whenever you want you can do this

```
removeAllText();
```

Comment: Would this be inside the function `nukeThisPage()`?

Comment: Yeah, or inside `if (!jQuery) { nukeThisPageYouHater() }` ;)

Comment: This is pretty pointless with a `*`; it’s equivalent to `document.documentElement.removeChild(document.head); document.documentElement.removeChild(document.body);`, usually.

Comment: @minitech how about now?

Comment: I forgot for a second that removing the text removes the elements too :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex. Use something like loadXMLDoc() to parse the DOM and print the tags, instead of trying to remove the values from within the tags.

Comment: HTML is not valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

Tested i JS and work for me:

```
String.replace(/<yourtag>[\s\S]*<\/yourtag>/g, "");
```