# how to limit character number in ng-bind-html in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

How can I limit number of characters for ng-bind-html result in angularJS? Is it possible?

For example there is `<span>some text </span>` in js file and with `$sce` and `ng-bind-html` transform to html.

I want to show `som..`. How can I limit it?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064319/angularjs-limitto-using-html-tags) is yours answer!!! pretty nice!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the limiTo filter in your controller - [limitTo fliter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo).

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$sce','$filter',
function($scope, $sce, $filter) {
    var dataObj = [];        
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        var content = $filter('limitTo')(data[i].Content, 150)
        var itemObj = {
            Content: $sce.trustAsHtml(content)
        }
        dataObj.push(itemObj);
    }
    $scope.ngRepeatArray = dataObj;  
}])
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in ngRepeatArray">
          <p ng-bind-html="item.Content"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

[AngularJS limitTo using HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064319/angularjs-limitto-using-html-tags)

@Sericaia had a great answer

She creates a custom filter like so:

```
angular.module('limitHtml', [])
    .filter('limitHtml', function() {
        return function(text, limit) {

            var changedString = String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
            var length = changedString.length;

            return length > limit ? changedString.substr(0, limit - 1) : changedString;
        }
    });
```

And then utilizes it in the view:

```
<span ng-bind-html="text | limitHtml: maxNumberOfChar"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to do some CSS tricks on your model represenation in html. For example if you have long text you can limit number of lines like here [Limit text length to n lines using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

To add a "read more" or "..." at the end of the truncated text, I added a small tweak to [@Yeysides's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32742941/2172146) extending [@Sericaia's "AngularJS limitTo using HTML tags"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064319/angularjs-limitto-using-html-tags).

Use a variable with the `suffix` string, then call it.

```
angular.module('limitHtml', [])
    .filter('limitHtml', function() {
        return function(text, limit) {

            var changedString = String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
            var length = changedString.length;
            var suffix = ' ...';

            return length > limit ? changedString.substr(0, limit - 1) + suffix : changedString;
        }
    });
```

And then utilizes it in the view:

```
<span ng-bind-html="text | limitHtml: maxNumberOfChar"></span>
```

Comment: This works for AngularJS, not Angular 2. I have it tested and deployed. Have you checked if the filter is being triggered correctly?

Comment: It works for me, but I did declare a variable for `maxNumberOfChar` in the controller scope. eg `$scope.maxNumberOfChar = 100;`