# See More or See Less in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have come across some few codes that works for appending text in AngularJS. However, it becomes a problem when the html is parsed. Here's my sample code to display the text.

```
<span class="text" ng-bind-html="parseTrustedHtml(profile.bio)"></span>
```

The tutorials available online for AngularJS works if the html is not parsed. That is, `{{profile.bio}}` but this is not what i want.

Is there any method I've missed where I could set this up so that there's a "see more" option after a say, 500 characters and "see less" option?

Comment: actually you don't need to parse your HTML. If you include `ngSanitize` in your main module the `ng-bind-html` directive will automatically parse your HTML as trusted. [see doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. Is your question about displaying HTML, or about truncating text to 500 characters, or what? Tell us what you want to achieve, and what the problem is.

Comment: It's about shortening the text displayed in html and use a "see more" to extend.

Comment: look into this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064319/angularjs-limitto-using-html-tags

Answer (score 2):

This could help you:

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tsqkv1nd6CC8e5Kr9pdU?p=preview)**

try to decorate with `<p read-more>` attribute

```
app.directive('readMore', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<p></p>',
    scope: {
      moreText: '@',
      lessText: '@',
      words: '@',
      ellipsis: '@',
      char: '@',
      limit: '@',
      content: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl, transclude) {
      var moreText = angular.isUndefined(scope.moreText) ? ' <a class="read-more">Read More...</a>' : ' <a class="read-more">' + scope.moreText + '</a>',
        lessText = angular.isUndefined(scope.lessText) ? ' <a class="read-less">Less ^</a>' : ' <a class="read-less">' + scope.lessText + '</a>',
        ellipsis = angular.isUndefined(scope.ellipsis) ? '' : scope.ellipsis,
        limit = angular.isUndefined(scope.limit) ? 150 : scope.limit;

      attr.$observe('content', function(str) {
        readmore(str);
      });

      transclude(scope.$parent, function(clone, scope) {
        readmore(clone.text().trim());
      });

      function readmore(text) {

        var text = text,
          orig = text,
          regex = /\s+/gi,
          charCount = text.length,
          wordCount = text.trim().replace(regex, ' ').split(' ').length,
          countBy = 'char',
          count = charCount,
          foundWords = [],
          markup = text,
          more = '';

        if (!angular.isUndefined(attr.words)) {
          countBy = 'words';
          count = wordCount;
        }

        if (countBy === 'words') { // Count words

          foundWords = text.split(/\s+/);

          if (foundWords.length > limit) {
            text = foundWords.slice(0, limit).join(' ') + ellipsis;
            more = foundWords.slice(limit, count).join(' ');
            markup = text + moreText + '<span class="more-text">' + more + lessText + '</span>';
          }

        } else { // Count characters

          if (count > limit) {
            text = orig.slice(0, limit) + ellipsis;
            more = orig.slice(limit, count);
            markup = text + moreText + '<span class="more-text">' + more + lessText + '</span>';
          }
        }

        elem.append(markup);
        elem.find('.read-more').on('click', function() {
          $(this).hide();
          elem.find('.more-text').addClass('show').slideDown();
        });
        elem.find('.read-less').on('click', function() {
          elem.find('.read-more').show();
          elem.find('.more-text').hide().removeClass('show');
        });

      }
    }
  };
```

The credit should go to [pattycam](http://plnkr.co/users/pattycam)

Comment: Not sure if this would work. I'll have a look and see what happens :)

Answer (score 1):

One simple way I can think of is apply filter `limitTo:limitvar`

```
{{ 'some text' | limitTo:2 }} // displays "so"
```

and change the `limitvar` variable accordingly with a `ng-click`. The filter will limit the number of chars to view as set by the `limitvar`.

### update

still somewhat naive and it doesn't solve the html tags problem, but I can't think of a way to do that properly :)

```
limitvar = 50;
parseTrustedHtml(bio) {
  //...
  var item = $filter('limitTo')(bio, limitvar );
  return $sce.trustAsHtml(item);
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/m89p9gbx8jJ5Xhu2H8aI?p=preview

Comment: This is easily achievable and not something I'm asking for. Thank you though :)

Comment: aha! I see now the problem you're having.. sorry for the irrelevant answer :)

Answer (score 1):

[view-more-less](https://github.com/cynx/view-more-less) is a tiny angularjs directive to convert any list into view-more-less list. this works with deferred list as well. there is no external dependancy with jQuery or other libraries.

All you need to do is place the element as last item in the list you want to convert:

```
<ul>
 <li>item 1</li>
 <li>item 2</li>
 ...
 <view-more-less />
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Controller

```
$scope.numLimit=100;
$scope.numLimitFlag = false;
$scope.readMore=function(flag){
  if(flag){
    $scope.numLimit=10000;
    $scope.numLimitFlag = flag;
  } else {
    $scope.numLimit=100;
    $scope.numLimitFlag = flag;
  }
};
```

In Html

```
<span style="font-size:15px;">
  <label><b>Name</b></label>
  <b>{{myName | limitTo:numLimit}}</b>
  <a type='button' ng-if="!numLimitFlag" ng-click="readMore(true)">Read more</a> 
  <a type='button' ng-if="numLimitFlag" ng-click="readMore(false)">Read less</a>
</span>
```